# Freeswitch - luarun script.lua from IVR using menu-exec-app fails

Tags: lua, freeswitch, ivr

I'm trying to run lua script from Freeswitch IVR, when caller press 1 I need to run lua script but it just fails

```
menu-exec-app:luarun survey2db.lua 111 222
```

any idea why `menu-exec-app: transfer` works, but the one above fails?

Above mentioned command (`luarun survey2db.lua 111 222`) works properly from fs_cli

Comment: What is error you facing?

Answer (score 0):

you should do it like this:

```
menu-exec-app:lua survey2db.lua 111 222
```